# EditControlShowing not adding items to ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am adding items to my ComboBox (inside a `DataGridView`) dynamically. When the `EditControlShowing` event fires I am able to load all the items into the list correctly, but every time I make a selection change only my first item remains in the combo box?

I've also used the Commit method to commit the changes to the dgv but still no luck.

Note: cboItem was a small class object that is re made in a for loop with new values, it is this object that I must add to the combo box.

Here's the code I used to add (Note this is inside `EditControlShowing`):

```
 cellComboBox.Items.Add(cboItem)
 dgvEmails.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
 dgvEmails.SelectedRows(0).Cells("cboFileTo").ValueType = GetType(cboItem)
 dgvEmails.EndEdit()
```

Comment: can you paste the cboItem declaration? how do you create it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Vland, was not in the office. What I discovered was that I had the combobox made in designer and on the EditingControlShowing event I was direct casting it to the a combo box, from there I had to add the cboItem to BOTH the casted combo-box and the designer made combo-box. This is quite odd and abysmal

Comment: @Vland I'll show the code tomorrow